# Unit testing with database created by Entity Framework with Effort and dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create fake database instance using Effort, but I encountered to a problem. `ObjectContextFactory` has a `CreateTransistent` generic method which expects an `ObjectContext` type to be defined:

```
public static T CreateTransient<T>( ) where T : ObjectContext;
```

So as far as I understand generic types I can define:

```
class MyObjectContextClass : ObjectContext
{
   //Entity definition here
}
```

So I can do following in unit test class:

```
var effortContext = ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient<MyObjectContextClass>()
```

So far so good, right? But my context class inherits from `dbContext` class:

```
class MyRealDbContextClass : DbContext
{
    // Entity definition here
}
```

I found that `DbContext` is a wrapper class and it consist of `ObjectContext`

So my question is: how can I retrieve type of my custom `ObjectContext` so I can use it in effort static method? I need something like:

```
var type = MyRealDbContextClass.GetObjectContextType();
```

So I can:

```
var effortContext = ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient<type>()
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is that I define a method in my Base test class (since this method will be required by all tests) to generate my dbset like:

```
public static IDbSet<T> GenerateSet<T>(IList<T> data) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        IDbSet<T> dbSet = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<T>, IQueryable>();
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.Provider).Return(queryable.Provider);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.Expression).Return(queryable.Expression);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.ElementType).Return(queryable.ElementType);
        dbSet.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(x => queryable.GetEnumerator());

        return dbSet;
    }
```

And then in my Test classes i can do something like:

```
[TestClass()]
public class ConcreteText: TestBase
{    
    private IMyDbContext _context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public new void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        _context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyDbContext>();
        _context.Stub(x => x.DbSetName).PropertyBehavior(); // Name of your dbset
        _context.DbSetName = GenerateSet(DbSetCollection); // Define a mock dbset collection
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
var effortContext = ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient<MyObjectContextClass>()
```

I used:

```
var con = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(connectionString);
```

Then I can use the effort DB connection in my DbContext class

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MC.ClientApi.CompanyProfile.Repository
{
    public partial class MyDBCoreDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBCoreDBEntities(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
        public MyDBCoreDBEntities(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }
    }
}
```

Full example of how I am doing my unit testing:

My repository method uses a factory to create the context

Repository:

```
public class OrganizationOptionsRepository : BaseEFRepository, IOrganizationOptionsRepository
    {
        private readonly IContextFactory ContextFactory;

        public OrganizationOptionsRepository(IContextFactory contextFactory)
        {
            ContextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public Result<IList<Country>> GetAllCountries()
        {
            using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateNew())
            {
                IQueryable<Country> query = context.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.NiceName);
                IList<Country> resultList = query.FromCache().ToList();
                return Result.Ok(resultList);
            }
        }
    }
```

Factory:

```
public class ContextFactory : IContextFactory
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public ContextFactory(string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = CreateEFConnectionString(connectionString, RepositoryConst.EdmxName);
        }

        public MyDBCoreDBEntities CreateNew()
        {
            return new MyDBCoreDBEntities(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

My unit test inherits from my factory and returns the effort context instead of the real context

```
public class TestContextFactory : IContextFactory
    {
        public MyDBCoreDBEntities CreateNew()
        {
            var connectionString = "sampleConnString";
            var con = Effort.EntityConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent(connectionString);
            return new MyDBCoreDBEntities(con);
        }


    }
```

My test initialize method:

```
   [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            ContextFactory = new TestContextFactory();
            _Context = ContextFactory.CreateNew();
            Repository = new NyDBRepository(ContextFactory);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I faced the same challenge today. Although, I doubt the answer is going to be any help to the OP, hopefully it's going to save time to some other poor souls forced to maintain legacy codebase.

So, if you want to utilize a fully in-memory data access via DbContext, with Effort and EntityFramework 6, and you are not sure about piecing `ObjectContext` together with `DbContext`, then follow these steps:

1. Use [CsvTool](https://entityframework-effort.net/export-data-to-csv) provided with Effort to export your DB to csv files.
2. Use [CsvDataLoader](https://entityframework-effort.net/load-data-from-csv) to load the previously exported data.
3. Use [ObjectContextFactory](https://entityframework-effort.net/fake-object-context-instance) to create an instance of `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext` OR `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext` (depending on the EF version used).
4. Create your instance of `DbContext` that works the loaded data.

Steps 2-4 summarized in a snippet:

```
var dataLoader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader("/directory/containing/exported/csv/files");
// the connection string below doesn't need to be working because it won't be used,
// it just has to be in the correct format
// ObjectContext type comes from EF
var objectContext = Effort.ObjectContextFactory.CreatePersistent<ObjectContext>("connection string", dataLoader);
// you might need to declare the constructor on your concrete context's class (in my case MyAwesomeDatabaseEntities)
// and pass the parameters to DbContext's constructor
var dbContext = new MyAwesomeDatabaseEntities(objectContext, dbContextOwnsObjectContext: true)
```